# Mouse click event coordinates are not matching or aligned with the found chessboard corner coordinates - EmguCV / WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, kinect, emgucv

I'm currently using the EmguCV library along with Kinect to create a simple hit test using WPF. I'm able to succesfully find the chessboard corners and store them in a list of rectangles as 4 corners of rectangles, then I'm trying to use a LeftMouseButtonUp event to get the mouse position and check whether it lies in the boundary any of the rectangles.

The problem is that I suspect that the coordinates returned by EmguCV as chessboard corners and the ones return from the mouse click event arent aligned, therefore it cannot detect a hit (i.e. a mouse click within a rectangle). How to get these two coordinates aligned together? Am I missing something?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EmguMotionTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" >
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="rgbImage" Stretch="Fill" MouseLeftButtonUp="rgbImage_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        <Line Name="line" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Visible" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    /*Kinect Initialization*/
    KinectSensor _kinectSensor;

    /*Getting the Chessboard corners*/
    PointF[] corners = new PointF[] { };
    PointF[] points = new PointF[4];
    List<PointF> cornerPts = new List<PointF>();
    List<List<PointF>> rectangle = new List<List<PointF>>();
    /*Defining the Chessboard parameters */
    const int width = 4;
    const int height = 4;
    Drawing.Size boardSize = new Drawing.Size(width, height);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Unloaded += delegate
        {
            _kinectSensor.ColorStream.Disable();
        };

        this.Loaded += delegate
        {
            _kinectSensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];

            _kinectSensor.ColorStream.Enable();
            _kinectSensor.Start();

            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += (a, b) => Pulse();
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (c, d) => bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        };
    }

    /*Polling event to retrieve Data from Kinect*/
    private void Pulse()
    {
        using (ColorImageFrame imageFrame = _kinectSensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(200))
        {
            if (imageFrame == null)
                return;

            //Converting a Kinect Color Frame to EmguCV Image
            Image<Bgr, Byte> imageCap = imageFrame.ToOpenCVImage<Bgr, Byte>();

            Image<Gray, Byte> gray = imageCap.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

            corners = CameraCalibration.FindChessboardCorners(gray, boardSize, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.ADAPTIVE_THRESH | Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.FILTER_QUADS);

            if (corners != null)
            {
                CvInvoke.cvFindCornerSubPix(gray, corners, corners.Length, new Drawing.Size(11, 11), new Drawing.Size(-1, -1), new MCvTermCriteria(30, 0.1));
                CameraCalibration.DrawChessboardCorners(gray, boardSize, corners);

                //Displaying the result in WPF
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                       new Action(() => rgbImage.Source = gray.ToBitmapSource())
                       );
            }
            else
            {
                //Displaying the result in WPF
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                       new Action(() => rgbImage.Source = gray.ToBitmapSource())
                       );
            }

        }
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            //Clear out the List of points 
            if (cornerPts != null)
            {
                cornerPts.Clear();
            }

            //Enter all the found corners into an array stored as polygons
            for (int i = 0; i < boardSize.Height - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < boardSize.Width - 1; j++)
                {
                    //Getting the corners of the squares (Square 1, 2, 3)..
                    int p1 = (i * boardSize.Width) + j;
                    int p2 = (i * boardSize.Width) + j + 1;
                    int p3 = ((i + 1) * boardSize.Width) + j;
                    int p4 = ((i + 1) * boardSize.Width) + j + 1;

                    //Add range method

                    points[0] = corners[p1];
                    points[1] = corners[p2];
                    points[2] = corners[p3];
                    points[3] = corners[p4];

                    cornerPts.AddRange(points);
                    rectangle.Add(new List<PointF>() { points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3] });
                }
            }
        }

        /*To test the corners points are being added correctly */
        if (e.Key == Key.D)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("D button press registered");

            ///*Test Square */
            for (int c = 0; c < rectangle.Count; c++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Triangle no: " + c + "," + n + rectangle[c][n]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void rgbImage_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(rgbImage);
        Console.WriteLine("MouseX: " + p.X + "," + "MouseY: " + p.Y);

        Console.WriteLine("-------------Hit Test---------------");
        /*Test Square */
        for (int c = 0; c < rectangle.Count; c++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Triangle no: " + c + "," + n + rectangle[c][n]);

                if ((p.X > rectangle[c][0].X && p.X < rectangle[c][1].X) && (p.Y > rectangle[c][0].Y && p.Y < rectangle[c][2].Y))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Triangle HIT is triangle no: " + c);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouse position had to be scaled according to the image. To get the correct pixel value

So in the Pulse() method extract the Bitmap's PixelWidth and PixelHeight and scale the mouse position according to the image control

```
/*Polling event to retrieve Data from Kinect*/
    private void Pulse()
    {

        using (ColorImageFrame imageFrame = _kinectSensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(200))
        {
            if (imageFrame == null)
                return;

            //Converting a Kinect Color Frame to EmguCV Image
            Image<Bgr, Byte> imageCap = imageFrame.ToOpenCVImage<Bgr, Byte>();

            Image<Gray, Byte> gray = imageCap.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

            corners = CameraCalibration.FindChessboardCorners(gray, boardSize, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.ADAPTIVE_THRESH | Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.FILTER_QUADS);

            if (corners != null)
            {
                CvInvoke.cvFindCornerSubPix(gray, corners, corners.Length, new Drawing.Size(11, 11), new Drawing.Size(-1, -1), new MCvTermCriteria(30, 0.1));
                CameraCalibration.DrawChessboardCorners(gray, boardSize, corners);

                pixelWidth = gray.ToBitmapSource().PixelWidth;
                pixelHeight = gray.ToBitmapSource().PixelHeight;

                //Displaying the result in WPF
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                       new Action(() => rgbImage.Source = gray.ToBitmapSource())
                       );
            }
            else
            {
                //Displaying the result in WPF
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                       new Action(() => rgbImage.Source = gray.ToBitmapSource())
                       );

            }
        }
    }

    private void rgbImage_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(rgbImage);

        var pixelMousePosX = e.GetPosition(rgbImage).X * pixelWidth / rgbImage.ActualWidth;
        var pixelMousePosY = e.GetPosition(rgbImage).Y * pixelHeight / rgbImage.ActualHeight;

        Console.WriteLine("MousePixelX: " + pixelMousePosX + "," + "MousePixelY: " + pixelMousePosY);

        /*Test Square */
        for (int c = 0; c < rectangle.Count; c++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
            {
                if ((pixelMousePosX > rectangle[c][0].X && pixelMousePosX < rectangle[c][1].X) && (pixelMousePosY > rectangle[c][0].Y && pixelMousePosY < rectangle[c][2].Y))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Triangle HIT is triangle no: " + c);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```